# Running two foreach loop

Tags: c#, loops

if i have two foreach loops something like below:

```
foreach(var a in b)
foreach(var c in d)

combining them into single foreach loop
foreach(var e in both b and d)
```

Comment: Are the loops inside each other (`foreach (var a in b) { foreach (var c in d) { /*...*/ }}`) or after each other (`foreach (var a in b) {} foreach (var c in d) {}`) ?

Comment: Just run one loop, then run the second loop. That will execute them after each other.

Answer (score 11):

No, there is no "in both" syntax. It is unclear *quite* what you are after. If you want to concatenate, then

```
foreach(var e in b.Concat(d))
```

If you want the combined set:

```
foreach(var e in b.Union(d))
```

Or the set common to both:

```
foreach(var e in b.Intersect(d))
```

If you want a cross-join, then maybe `SelectMany`. But frankly, for that, a nested `foreach` is just as reasonable and effective in your case.

Comment: i'm looking to select xml node elements in a single foreach loop

Comment: @user1502952 that statement does not make the context any clearer. A concrete example *might*.

Comment: var b=from result in doc.descendants("Xmlnode") select new{resultone=result.Attribute("node").value,resulttwo=result.element("elementone").value} similarly for var d .. i need to select the elements of both in single foreach loop

Comment: ok i can use like this foreach(var a in b)foreach(var c in d){both xml node elements visible}